# Is it possible to group by column with join?

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot, aggregate-functions

```
select tc.UIDPK,
count(torder.status) as total
from TCUSTOMER tc
inner join TORDER torder on tc.UIDPK=torder.CUSTOMER_UID
where tc.UIDPK=490000;
```

the above query working fine for me.
however the status can be IN_PROGRESS,FAILED,ON_HOLD

How can i write a query which returns count of status
like
tc.UIDPK, count of total orders, count of IN_PROGRESS orders, count of total orders-count of IN_PROGRESS orders.
I tried below but not working

```
select tc.UIDPK,
count(torder.status) as total,
count(torder2.status) as inprogress,
count(torder.status)-count(torder2.status) as remaining
from TCUSTOMER tc
inner join TORDER torder on tc.UIDPK=torder.CUSTOMER_UID
left join TORDER torder2 on tc.UIDPK=torder2.CUSTOMER_UID and torder2.status in('IN_PROGRESS')
where tc.UIDPK=490000;
```

Comment: "...the above query working fine for me..." -- No, it doesn't. The query is unpredictable as written, and you may be getting the results you want by chance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for multiple joins, use SUM.

Try

```
select tc.UIDPK,
       COUNT(torder.status) as total,
       SUM(torder.status = 'IN_PROGRESS') as inprogress,
       COUNT(torder.status) - SUM(torder.status = 'IN_PROGRESS') as remaining
from TCUSTOMER tc
inner join TORDER torder on tc.UIDPK=torder.CUSTOMER_UID
where tc.UIDPK=490000
group by tc.UIDPK;
```

Comment: thanks. it helped me. i tweaked it to my needs and it worked

Comment: `SUM(torder.status)` would probably be better phrased `COUNT(*)`.